# Converting Excel Column with To SSRS (inch or pt)

Tags: excel, reporting-services

I have report in Excel that I user gave me and wants the same exact format in the new SSRS report.  So if I have a column in excel of the width 14.14 (103 pixels) what should that be for the width of that column in SSRS ( in, mm, cm, pt, or pc)?

I can't get the correct factor because it seems to differ based on size?

```
Excel Width     Pixels   Ratio  
0.08            1        0.08   
0.83            10       0.083  
13.57           100      0.1357 ??
142.14          1000     0.14214    
254.71          1788     0.142455257
```

I understand pixels per inch is dpi dependent, but what I am looking for is a printable equivalent.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Excel (and many other MS related apps) default to [96 pixels per inch](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/excel-help/measurement-units-and-rulers-in-excel-HP001151724.aspx).

So your 103 pixel wide Excel column should be:
103 / 96 = 1.073 inches (Rounded to thousands.)

Of course many printing options will change this, such as "Fit on one page."

Answer (score 4):

Here is what I found out about the relationship between excel and ssrs. It seems excel uses 96 pixels per inch. I also found using units of PT in ssrs translates much more accurately into excel and is actually mentioned somewhere in the MSDN documentaiton.

In excel a column of 10 = 75 pixels, 20 = 145 pixels, etc.
Basically the units are 70 plus an additional 5 pixels.

So to set the column in ssrs I used:

[Width in PT] = ([width in excel] / 10 * 70 + 5) / 96 * 72)

For example:
Width 10 in excel = 75 pixels = 56.25 pts = .78125"

Answer (score 2):

I used RhodeHummels answer, however I had to change it because there is a missing parenthesis in the answer, I believe it should read:

[Width in PT] = **((**[Width in excel]/10 * 70 + 5)/ 96 * 72)

e.g. =((10/10*70+5)/96*72) gets the desired answer in excel